# React typing effect on 3 containers with strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a typing effect in React on 3 containers that are lined up and holding strings within them. The effect should start from the leftmost container after it finishes typing its string, it starts the container that comes after it, and so on.

I started with an idea where I store all the strings in an array and initialize a new array called currentText with a new letter every second but I probably just made things more complicated for myself.

Perhaps there is a simpler solution?

My complicated and not working solution looks like this:

```
    const [text, setText] = useState([]);
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
    const [currentText, setCurrentText] = useState([]);


    // Setting Text Content For Typing
    useEffect(() => {
        if(log && log.length > 0 && text.length == 0){
            log.map((item, key) => {
                let time = item['time'];
                let message = item['message'];
                let event = item['eventid'];
                setText((prev) => [...prev, time, message, event]);
            });
        }
    }, [log, text]);


    useEffect(() => {
            if(currentText?.length < text?.length){
                const interval = setInterval(()=> {

                    // Setting Current index
                    if(currentText?.length !== 0 && currentIndex !== currentText?.length -1) {
                        setCurrentIndex(currentText?.length -1);
                    }
                    
                    // Check if the last index string completed
                    if(currentText[currentIndex]?.length !== text[currentIndex]?.length){
                        let temp = currentText;
                        let lastText = temp[currentIndex];
                        if(lastText) lastText = lastText + text[currentIndex].charAt(lastText?.length -1);
                        else lastText = text[currentIndex].charAt(0);
                        temp[currentIndex] = lastText;
                        setCurrentText(temp);
                    }
                    // If completed open new array element to contain new string
                    else{
                        setCurrentText((prev) => [...prev, ['']]);
                    }
            }, 1000);
            return () => clearInterval(interval);
            }

    }, [currentText, text, currentIndex]);


return (
    <>
       {
          currentText && currentText.length > 0 && 
                    currentText.map((item, key) => {
                            <div key={key} className={classes.row}>
                                <span className={classes.time}>{currentText[key]}</span>
                                <span className={classes.message}>{key % 1 ? currentText[key] : currentText[key+1]}</span>
                                <span className={classes.event}>{key % 2 ? currentText[key] : currentText[key+2]}</span>
                            </div>
                        })
        }
```

The log look like this:

```
[
{time: '2023-02-19 06:25:30', message: 'some message', eventid: 'event_string'},
{time: '2023-02-19 06:25:30', message: 'some message', eventid: 'event_string'},
{time: '2023-02-19 06:25:30', message: 'some message', eventid: 'event_string'},
]
```

Comment: Can you include the code for `log`

Comment: I included the log array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Define an array of log objects
const logs = [
  { time: '2023-02-19 06:25:30', message: 'some message', eventid: 'event_string' },
  { time: '2023-02-19 06:25:30', message: 'some message', eventid: 'event_string' },
  { time: '2023-02-19 06:25:30', message: 'some message', eventid: 'event_string' },
];

// Define a component that renders a paragraph tag with a substring of text
function TextComponent(props) {
  const { index = 0, text } = props;
  return <p> {text.substring(0, index)}</p>;
}

// Define a component that types out the text of its children components
function TypeWriter(props) {

  // Destructure the props and get the number of children
  const { children, charTime = 50 } = props;
  const nChildrens = React.Children.count(children);

  // Throw an error if there are no children
  if (nChildrens < 1) throw new Error('Type writer component must have children');

  // Define the state of the component, which keeps track of which child is currently active and how much of its text has been typed out
  const [activeComponent, setActiveComponent] = React.useState({
    children: 0,
    index: 0,
    length: children[0].props.text.length,
  });

  // Use the useEffect hook to update the state every time the interval elapses
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Set an interval that updates the state by typing out a single character every time it is called
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setActiveComponent((state) => {
        // If the current child's text has been completely typed out, move on to the next child
        if (state.index > state.length) {
          if (state.children < nChildrens - 1)
            return {
              index: 0,
              children: state.children + 1,
              length: children[state.children + 1].props.text.length,
            };

          // If there are no more children, clear the interval and return the current state
          clearInterval(interval);
          return state;
        }
        
        // Otherwise, update the state to type out the next character
        return { ...state, index: state.index + 1 };
      });
    }, charTime);

    // Return a function to clear the interval when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  });

  // Render the children components, with the active child being typed out and the others already fully typed out
  return (
    <div>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          key: index,
          index:
            index === activeComponent.children
              ? activeComponent.index
              : index < activeComponent.children
              ? child.props.text.length
              : 0,
        });
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

// Define a component that renders a TypeWriter component with TextComponents as its children
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <TypeWriter>
      {logs.map((log, index) => (
        <TextComponent key={index} text={log.message} />
      ))}
    </TypeWriter>
  );
}
```